# receiving this msg from zend: 'Zend_Soap_Client_Exception' with message 'Invalid URN'

Tags: zend-framework, wsdl, soap-client, zend-soap

does anyone know what this means
im doing a pretty simple call here in my indexAction -

```
    private $wsdl = "https://mywsdlserver.com/open?wsdl";
    $options = array(
                "location"=>$this->wsdl,
                "uri"=>$this->wsdl
            );

    $client = new Zend_Soap_Client($this->wsdl, $options);
    print_r($client);
```

fyi i have tried this with and without the options
when i set the options i get the error
when i dont set the options i get an empty client

what id like to get back 
is the xml i get when i just put https://mywsdlserver.com/open?wsdl in the addressbar

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the URL you are passing in the options is not valid. The one in your example is fine, so presumably this is not what you are really using.

However, the location and URI options don't apply in WSDL mode, so you're best off omitting them completely. See the docs for the Zend_Soap_Client constructor at: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.client.html